# Return data from multiple child tables in same row

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, union, union-all

I've some tables related by foreign keys from where I need to get data from, their structure is something like:

```
    Table A                Intermediate A              Child A
| id |   Data          | idTableA | idChildA        | id | Child A
| 1  | 'Data 1'        | 1        | 1               | 1  | 'Child 1'
| 2  | 'Data 2'        | 1        | 2               | 2  | 'Child 2'
| 3  | 'Data 3'        | 1        | 3               | 3  | 'Child 3'
                       | 2        | 4               (...)
                       | 2        | 5
                       | 3        | 6
                       | 3        | 6

                           Intermediate B              Child B
                       | idTableA | idChildB        | id | Child B
                       | 1        | 4               | 4  | 'Child 1'
                       | 1        | 5               | 5  | 'Child 2'
                       | 1        | 6               | 6  | 'Child 3'
                       | 2        | 6               (...)
                       | 2        | 7
                       | 3        | 8
                       | 3        | 9
```

What I'm trying to do is to get all the records from both child tables that coincide with `Table A` key in the intermediate tables but without combining the data. Something like this:

```
                  Result
|idTableA|ChildA  |Child B |
|1       |'Child1'|null    |
|1       |'Child2'|null    |
|1       |'Child3'|null    |
|1       |null    |'Child4'|
|1       |null    |'Child5'|
|1       |null    |'Child6'|
|2       |'Child4'|null    |
|2       |'Child5'|null    |
|2       |null    |'Child6'|
|2       |null    |'Child7'|
(...)
```

I've been applying to intermediate tables and from there to child tables only to unsuccessfully retrieve mixed data from child tables where I'm supposed to get null values.

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you also want to include rows from Table A with *no* related row in either child table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should select the rows from the separate child tables and then do a `UNION` between those two clauses, specifying `NULL` for the fields from the other child table:

```
SELECT main1.id AS idTableA, ca.childA, NULL::text AS childB
FROM tableA main1
JOIN intermediateA ia ON main1.id = ia.idTableA
JOIN childA ca ON ca.id = ia.idChildA

UNION

SELECT main2.id AS idTableA, NULL, cb.childB
FROM tableA main2
JOIN intermediateB ib ON main2.id = ib.idTableA
JOIN childB cb ON cb.id = ib.idChildB

ORDER BY 1, 2, 3;
```

Comment: Finally could solve this problem after implementing your query. Thank you so much!.

Answer (score 1):

[What @Patrick says.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40559430/939860)
But unless you  ...

- want to include rows from Table A with no related row in either child table
- or you want to eliminate `idTableA` values not present in Table A (not possible with FK constraint)

... you don't need to include Table A in the query *at all*. (Else you need a `LEFT JOIN`.)

```
SELECT ia.idTableA, ca.childA, NULL::text AS childB
FROM   intermediateA ia
JOIN   childA ca ON ca.id = ia.idChildA

UNION ALL  -- ! 

SELECT ib.idTableA, NULL, cb.childB
FROM   intermediateB ib
JOIN   childB cb ON cb.id = ib.idChildB

ORDER   BY 1, 2, 3;
```

And make that `UNION ALL`. Cheaper, and you do not want to attempt to fold duplicates here.

Comment: I guess you are using `UNION ALL` like an optimizer hint ("Move along please, nothing to see here") but have you considered that the human reader needs to unpick this too? I see `UNION ALL` as a way of creating a resultset with duplicate rows but I never want to do that! So I always use `UNION`. If this is expensive then I'm worth it, build me a smarter optimizer ...but before you do, prove to me that `UNION ALL` is "cheaper".

Comment: @onedaywhen: `UNION ALL` is obviously faster, just try for yourself. More importantly, if duplicate rows are not supposed to be eliminated, `UNION` is *wrong*, plain and simple. Insisting on it because you like the way it *looks* is ... well, not going anywhere. That's like insisting on a simple `JOIN` where the logic requires a `LEFT JOIN`, just because it's easier on the human eye. Even if it doesn't make a difference with the current data set, it's a bug waiting to happen. What if the column `Child A` isn't defined `UNIQUE` (by mistake)?

Comment: It's not about cosmetics lol, It's about the relational model. There are no duplicate tuples in RM, even in derived relations (query results), so I have no use case for `UNION ALL` in SQL. There are no nulls in RM, so I have no use case for `LEFT JOIN` in SQL.

Comment: @onedaywhen: `LEFT JOIN` can produce NULL values without any NULL in your model.

Comment: Indeed, which is why `LEFT JOIN` should be avoided (or if it is used, the nulls it would produce are not projected in the result).